# Can not import .zip files in appmaker

Tags: google-app-maker

All of a sudden appmaker won't allow me to import an app exported from a different project.

I get the following errors in snackbar:

```
- error uploading application file. Please try again.
- unexpected client error.
```

And here are my webconsole logs:

```
SEVERE: Unexpected error
com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: Invalid file upload info data: 
    at Unknown.Cf(com.google.apps.appmaker.AppMakerGwt-0.js@59:126) .....
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid file upload info data: 
    at Unknown.Kf(com.google.apps.appmaker.AppMakerGwt-0.js@48:130) ......
```

Any ideas what is going on? I was doing the same thing yesterday and it was working fine!

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. It seems to be a bug with App Maker. Hopefully the engineers can take care of this soon.

Comment: As of today at 8:30am CST, the issue has been resolved for me. It was a bug due to some recent changes I see.

Answer (score 0):

A late answer but as @Morfinismo also confirmed its a bug and it has been solved long time ago.